# JSONObject.getString() returns nulll

Tags: android

I have got a JSONObject and having a value like :

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "City": {
        "1": "noida",
        "2": "Delhi",
        "3": "Kanpur",
        "4": "Gurgaon",
        "5": "Mumbai",
        "7": "Noida",
        "8": "NEWYORK",
        "9": "Patna"
    }
}
```

I have a key value regarding with every value but there is no value regarding the key "6". So it returns "No value for 6" exception. I am trying to remove this via using this code but failed... Please keep in mind that the cities are to be rendered in a spinner in the form of String[].

The code is as follows :

```
JSONObject jsonCities = jsonObject.getJSONObject("City");
                        int len = jsonCities.length();
                        Log.i("Length of jsonCities is :", ""+len);
                        for(int i=1;i<=len;i++)
                        {    
                            if(jsonCities.get(""+i)==null)
                        {
                                Log.i("NULL VALUE", "NULL VALUE");
                                continue;
                        }
                            else
                        {
                            Log.i("Cities :",""+jsonCities.getString(""+i));
                            cities_hashmap.put(""+i, ""+jsonCities.getString(""+i));
                            Log.i("cities_hashmap", ""+cities_hashmap);
                        }

                    }

                    cities = new String[cities_hashmap.size()];

                    for(int j=1;j<=cities_hashmap.size();j++)
                    {
                        Log.i("CITY IS :", cities_hashmap.get(""+j));

                        cities[j-1] = cities_hashmap.get(""+j);
                        Log.i("City Array in String form is :", ""+cities);

                    }


context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Registration.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities);
                                country.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this :

```
String value = jsonCities.getString(Integer.toString(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the key is available or not using has() method of JsonObject, its return true if the key was found other return false.

```
if(jsonCities.has(""+i)){
   // do the thing
}
```

check more method from this link

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Skip **6** as

```
    for(int i=1;i<=len;i++)
    {    
          if(i == 6 )
          {
               i += 1;
          }
          if(jsonCities.get(""+i)==null)
          {
               Log.i("NULL VALUE", "NULL VALUE");
               continue;
          }
          else
          {
               Log.i("Cities :",""+jsonCities.getString(""+i));
               cities_hashmap.put(""+i, ""+jsonCities.getString(""+i));
               Log.i("cities_hashmap", ""+cities_hashmap);
          }
          ...
          ...
```

Comment: Its not fix Sir... It may be possible then If I m selecting different value from another spinner..., then first record may be null.. This value is depend on another spinner

Comment: I have a spinner named countries.... on selecting of country... the corresponding cities are fetching from server. Anyway Sir,,,, I have got all the keys and corresponds values. Now I have added these key-value pairs in hashmap... Now the requirement is to put these values in spinner by passing String[].

Comment: Just take key from String[] and parse JSON array, it will be easy for you. Because now yo know all keys which are in you HashMap and String[], so take it from there and parse JSON Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this 'for' loop

```
for(int i=1;i<=len;i++)
```

with

```
Iterator it = jsonCities.keys();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String key = it.next().toString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: and how to get regarding values to these keys

Comment: I have a hashmap. The values of the hashmap are used in spinner. How can I identify the correspond key, which value is selected?

Comment: After you get the key, you only have to put "cities_hashmap.put(key,  jsonCities.getString(key));" and you are done.